Как оптимизировать работу с большими данными в Python 3.x: эффективное использование Pandas и NumPy?
Я работаю над проектом, который требует обработки очень больших объемов данных (миллионы строк). Использую библиотеки Pandas и NumPy для анализа данных, но сталкиваюсь с проблемами производительности. Хотел бы узнать у сообщества:

Какие есть методы и техники для оптимизации работы с большими DataFrame в Pandas?
Как эффективно использовать NumPy для ускорения операций с массивами?
Есть ли какие-то распространенные ошибки, которые могут негативно влиять на производительность, и как их избегать?
Какие альтернативные инструменты или библиотеки вы порекомендуете для работы с большими данными в Python 3.x?


Ну вы же опытный человек... Как бы сами на такой неконкретный вопрос отвечали?

Когда речь идёт о миллионах, пора переходить на базы данных. У меня в простенькое настольной базе данных sqlite3 3 млн. 240 тыс. записей. Выборки нужных групп записей, как минимум, происходят мгновенно.


Для оптимизации нужно во-первых понимать полностью процесс: что конкретно вы делаете. Без описания этапов того, что вы делаете, непонятно, что вообще оптимизировать, собственно.

Pandas - это не про скорость, это про удобство. Для обработки больших данных все эти удобства только в минус. Индексы, возможность иметь смешанные или сложные данные в столбцах и прочее такое - всё это тормозит обработку. Хотите быстро - используйте чистый Numpy, там лишнего ничего нет, только массивы однотипных данных, обрабатываемых максимально быстро.

Альтернативы Pandas есть, но не нужно рассматривать их как лёгкое решение проблемы. Всеми ими нужно уметь ещё правильно пользоваться и иметь для этого достаточно ресурсов. Примеры: Polars, Vaex, PySpark, уже упомянутый в другом ответе Dask.

Из простого. На Kaggle популярна такая оптимизация. Определяете диапазон и тип данных в столбце и выбираете для этого столбца наиболее "узкий" тип данных, в который данный столбец влезет, вместо того, который используется по умолчанию. Например, uint8. Для очень больших данных экономия на типе данных столбца может дать существенный выигрыш и в используемой памяти и во времени обработки данных.

В каких-то случаях может помочь и Numba, но ей тоже нужно уметь пользоваться. В каких-то случаях она может дать ускорение на порядок за счёт параллелизма и разных оптимизаций вычислений.





Какие есть методы и техники для оптимизации работы с большими DataFrame в Pandas?

Как эффективно использовать NumPy для ускорения операций с массивами?



Не надо искать методы и техники — возможно использовать Dask.

Датафрейм Dask — это просто коллекция многих датафреймов pandas. Но вам не нужно знать детали, с датафреймом Dask можете работать как с одним датафреймом pandas.

То же самое API, как pandas.

Большие размеры: Работает с 100 GiB на компьютере, или с 100 TiB на кластере.

Простое использование: Чистый Python, установка через pip или conda.

dask.array для работы с огромными numpy.array.

См. 10 Minutes to Dask.


